# Various notations in functional analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis

In most literature on functional analysis the notation for an inner product on an inner product space $H$ is usually denoted $ \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:H \times H \mapsto \mathbb{K} $.  However, I have noticed that some authors perfers to write it as $ (\cdot | \cdot)  $. Searching on the internet this leads me to believe that this has something to do with notations in physic, namely the bra-ket which are frequently applied in quantum mechanics.

However what seems interesting to me more is that, even if $H$ is just a Banach space without an inner product, sometimes a functionl on the dual space $H^{\ast}$ of $H$ is denoted as follows:
$$f:H^{\ast} \longrightarrow \mathbb{K} : x \longmapsto f(x) \Longleftrightarrow \langle f,x\rangle: H^{\ast} \times H \longrightarrow \mathbb{K} $$
which actually seems super useful because it has this analogy with the Cauchy  Schwarz inequality：
$$| \langle f,x\rangle  | \leq \| f\|_{\text{op}} \|x\|_{H} $$
since $f$ is bounded. Also if $T^{\ast}$ is the dual operator of $T:H \rightarrow H$ then one also has
$$\langle T^{\ast}f,x\rangle  = \langle f, Tx\rangle $$
which in some sense resembles the notion of an adjoint.

So my question is: what are these notations called and where they come from? In particular do they actually have anything to do with the notion of inner product?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A difference between the $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot\right\rangle$ notation is that it is bilinear in Banach spaces, but sesquilinear in (complex) Hilbert spaces (i.e. linear in one component, antilinear in the other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riesz representation theorem tells us for every $f \in H^*$ there exists an $y \in H$ such that $f(x) = \langle y,x \rangle$ for every $x \in H$, so this notation makes sense for Hilbert spaces.

Comment: The part on dual space also makes sense if $H$ is just normed.

Comment: It does indeed. On a Hilbert space $H$ this is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. If $X$ is a normed space, we call $\langle x, f \rangle := f(x)$ the dual pair.

Comment: There goes the name! Got it, thanks a lot!